# React router v6 modal reloading background page location (instead of saving scroll position)

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-router-dom

Working with React Router v6. I have routes set up so that backgroundLocation is passed to the Routes and a modal opens correctly with a different route as the background page. I came across unexpected behavior when opening a modal while scrolled down on the page though - the page 'reloads' so it's back at the top of the page and then opens the modal. When the modal closes, the background page shows correctly (scrolled down). It looks jittery. Instead, I want the modal to open/close without changing the scroll position of the background page. I followed the [RRDv6 modal example](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/modal?file=src%2FApp.tsx) quite closely.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Routes: React.FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const state = location.state as {
    backgroundLocation?: Location;
  };

  return (
      {/* Pass location to Routes so that Page remains background when ModalVersion is opened */}
      <Routes location={state?.backgroundLocation || location}>
        <Route path={'/'} element={<Home />} />
        <Route path={'/page'} element={<Page />} />
        <Route path={'/page/:more_info'} element={<PageVersion />} />
      </Routes>

      {/* Open Modal if state.backgroundLocation is defined */}
      {state?.backgroundLocation && (
        <Routes>
          <Route path={'/page/:more_info'} element={<ModalVersion />} />
        </Routes>
      )}
  )
```

...

```
import { Link } form "@mui/material"    
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Page: React.FC = () => {

 return (
   <APageComponentContainingALink>
    <Link
      component={RouterLink}
      to={"/page/some_info"}
      state={{ backgroundLocation: location }}
    >
      ...
    </Link>
   </ APageComponentContainingALink>
  )

}
export { Page };
```

...

```
  // Returns the same as PageVersion, but wrapped in a modal
  const ModalVersion: React.FC = () => {
    
      return (
        <Modal>
          <Info />
        </Modal>
      )
    
    }
    export { ModalVersion };
```

...

```
// Returns the same as ModalVersion, but on its own page
const PageVersion: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <Info />
  )

}
export { PageVersion };
```

Comment: I don't believe this is an issue with RRD. I think you may only need to adjust the modal component's positioning. Can you include all relevant code you are working with as a [mcve] so we can see what it's doing? It might also prove useful to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live.

Comment: I was putting a codesandbox demo together, and I couldn't get it to reproduce the problem... Then I noticed we have an app-wide ScrollToTop component from react router v5 (which Cassidy pointed out below) which is definitely causing the issue here. Thanks to both of you for your direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The React Router Scroll Restoration docs might be what you're looking for:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration

Without seeing the results, my assumption is that because the components are rendering/unmounting on a single page, there might be some height adjustment happening in the DOM. Doing these scroll restoration effects will likely stop that from happening.